# Filter specific range of hours to show in alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Tags: android

I'm using [Alamkanak's Week View Library](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View). It's great but I'm having trouble with a specific feature I want to add to my app. It needs to look like this:
[image]

But this calendar starts showing time at 01:00 and goes all the way to 00:00 the following day. I'm looking to only show hours that are important to me: from 09:00 to 20:00.
I've also searched into this a lot, even found the [same topic here](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/issues/42), but still no solution.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if you can recommend another library to use for showing such events (I didn't quite like Google Calendar), it can also be of high value. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be quite simple actually, (In my bellow explanation I've gone for the 07:00 - 19:00 hours)

Firstly copy the WeekView class and create a new WeekView class in your project.[enter link description here](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/alamkanak/weekview/WeekView.java)
Secondly, assuming you've got the  in your XML, you need to change that to
 to reflect the newly created class and that fact that we want to use that instead of the default one.

Then in your new WeekView class you're going to need

```
import com.alamkanak.weekview.DateTimeInterpreter;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.MonthLoader;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekViewEvent;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekViewLoader;
```

After that, in the      private void initTextTimeWidth() method, you'll need to update the for loop to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
```

Then in the  private void drawTimeColumnAndAxes(Canvas canvas) method you need to alter couple of things:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
...

  String time = getDateTimeInterpreter().interpretTime(i+7); //This will set the correct display hour digits
```

In the very next method drawHeaderRowAndEvents, update:

```
mEffectiveMinHourHeight= Math.max(mMinHourHeight, (int) ((getHeight() - mHeaderTextHeight - mHeaderRowPadding * 2 - mHeaderMarginBottom) / 12));
```

There's another for loop that needs updating

```
for (int hourNumber = 0; hourNumber < 12; hourNumber++) {
```

And lastly

```
float top = mHourHeight * 12 * mEventRects.get(i).top / 1440 + mCurrentOrigin.y + mHeaderTextHeight + mHeaderRowPadding * 2 + mHeaderMarginBottom + mTimeTextHeight/2 + mEventMarginVertical;

 bottom = mHourHeight * 12 * bottom / 1440 + mCurrentOrigin.y + mHeaderTextHeight + mHeaderRowPadding * 2 + mHeaderMarginBottom + mTimeTextHeight/2 - mEventMarginVertical;
```

Basically go trough all the 24s in the class and update those to whatever you like, in my case it's 12 as I'm going for a 12 hour time-span to show and add howevery many hours you want to, coresponding to your first starting hour in String time = getDateTimeInterpreter().interpretTime(i+7)

[Here's a paste bin](https://www.diffchecker.com/KgMb2f3V) to visualise all the crap from above, Left is the original class, right mine

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same library, and I've tried to make something similar once. What I can suggest is set the `goToHour(double);` to your first event's start time, than scale the hour's height with something like this to match your last event's end time:

```
int height = weekView.getMeasuredHeight();
int textSize = weekView.getTextSize();
int padding = weekView.getHeaderRowPadding();
height = height - textSize - (2 * padding);
weekView.setHourHeight(height / 24);
```

Edit: I've used this code to see whole 0-24 on the weekview. I think tweaking this could get you what you want.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and it's a solid idea, but I want to prevent users from ever seeing unnecessary time, since I'll never have events before 9:00 and after 20:00...

Comment: @MilanVucic I still do think that you can achieve this behaviour with that. You can calculate the desired timespan like ` calcualted timespan = lastEvent.endTime - firstEvent.startTime`, than in `setScrollListener()` you can update this timespan for every day than `setHourHeight(height / calculatedTimespan);`. After this you only need to `goToHour(firstEvent.startTime);` and you should have what you want I think.

Comment: and how can I prevent the user from scrolling and seeing the hours before 09:00 or after 20:00? Or pinch-zooming back out?