# Android - Build a event calendar UI. What components should I use?

Tags: android

I'm working on the app for event. I want to add calendar activity with columns as room, rows as time, and cells as attraction. I tried to use [Android Week View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View) package, but it has some limitations (columns as day, cannot set max/min date) and that's why I can't use it.

I'm going to do something like this:
[image: Goal]

I'm thinking how can I do that. Building on scratch using `View` class it's too hard for me (and I think exists a better idea). So, can you enlighten me what component could I use? TableView, RecyclerView? I'm looking for a solution with visible only 4 rooms (on smartphones), but by scrolling horizontal you can show more.

Comment: Hah, I have had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944431/filter-specific-range-of-hours-to-show-in-alamkanak-android-week-view). Tried using the same library, ended up creating everything on a canvas :) Had no luck finding a better solution :/ Really, really, really hard-work it was.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Recyclerview. Will require a lot of custom adapter code though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

It would be simple if you add `RecyclerView` in your xml and in java code just say

```
GridLayoutManager lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, NO_OF_COLUMNS);
RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
```